# Lyx: can't import LaTex file

Tags: lyx, import, covers

I'm trying to import [this](http://corsi.unibo.it/informatica-magistrale/Documents/frontespizio.tex.txt) latex document into Lyx (version 2.0.2 on Ubuntu 12.04), but it fails and won't give any explanation about the error:

```
Lyx: cannot convert file
 An error occurred while running: tex2lyx -f "frontespizio.tex" "frontespizio.lyx"
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: This works under [LyX 2.0.4](http://www.lyx.org) (with some minor editing, of course). Perhaps consider updating? Once that's done, give some more feedback.

Comment: Does importing fail, or compiling? I was able to import [*File --> Import --> LaTeX (plain)*] without errors, but it gave an error on compiling, but the PDF was still generated. Ubuntu 12.04, LyX 2.0.2.

Comment: I can't import it at all. Here's the output: `Lyx: cannot convert file
An error occurred while running:
tex2lyx -f "frontespizio.tex" "frontespizio.lyx"` I will update the question with this piece of information.

Comment: I updated to Lyx 2.0.4, but got the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*:

Importing the downloaded file into a non-UTF8 editor (like TeXnicCenter 1.0), reveals:

[image]

The first character could be the cause of the problem - called a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Even importing this into LyX 2.0.4 adds the following into the preamble (Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble):

[image]

which you'll have to remove. Either remove this from the file *first* before importing, or attempt an update of your version from 2.0.2 to 2.0.4 and remove it *after* importing.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any ordinary text editor that I can use to remove that first character? I can't seem to find it.    I also wanted to upgrade to Lyx 2.0.4, but www.lyx.org isn't responding.

Comment: Here is [a BOM-free version of `frontespizio.tex`](http://pastebin.com/kWEEi8NG) on Pastebin. Copy and paste this in a regular (UTF8-free) file/editor and (re)try importing it in LyX.

Comment: Thanks. I copied and pasted into gedit, but it didn't work. Same thing when I saved the file directly from pastebin. Updating to 2.0.4 also didn't work.  I don't know how to proceed at this point.

Comment: @RickyRobinson: Are you still getting the same error when importing using LyX 2.0.4? Here's the [LyX 2.0.4 file of `frontespizio.tex`](http://pastebin.com/jgiXaHfU). After importing I erased the BOM, as well as the two comments around some title.

Comment: I was getting the same error, yes.  But thank you so much for the .lyx file! This time of course it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

I did the importation when I open the tex file with Kile, after that opening it with TexnicCenter and finally the Lyx (2.1) in Windows.

Comment: That is very particular (what if I don't have Kile, say) and convoluted... it's most likely just because one of these applications strips unidentifiable characters...

Answer (score 0):

If you change the document class from `svjour3` to `revtex` and the converter works well! If you still need to work in a `svjour3` or `report` class, reconstruct an empty LyX file from the template and copy all things you obtained from the `revtex` class and this may solve the problem.