# Runtime error while importing a poster from .tex to .lyx

Tags: lyx, import, baposter

I try to import a `.tex` file (an A0 poster created from `baposter` template in some older version of MikTex) to Lyx (2.0.6), but the conversion fails with `Runtime error tex2lyx "poster.tex" "poster.lyx"` error message.

I made sure there are no characters which made problems [in this case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72780/36834). I guess the problem is in some missing support for the A0 poster class. Should this be fixed by some upgrade of LyX, or is it more complicated?

EDIT: I assured this error occurs only while importing A0 posters, LaTex document created from "article" template was imported correctly.

Comment: Please make a minimal example post it on an enhancement request here: http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @scottkosty: good tip, reported.

Comment: It's good practice to update your question with relevant links in case someone has a similar question. Thus: http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8846

Comment: When reporting feature requests, the chances of having it implemented increase _a lot_ if you give a minimal example. See here: http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample. In this case your minimal example would be a .tex file, not a .lyx file.

Comment: Minimal example uploaded.

Comment: Thanks, Pavel. Hopefully someone will have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LyX doesn't yet support LaTeX poster classes natively. This will likely be added in the future, as several LyX .layout files for poster classes are already readily available on the [LyX bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8714) (though not for 'baposter'). If you want to use a poster class in LyX, then install those layouts.